# Cell modification function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm taking my first steps in VBA and I am trying to make a function that allows me to change the value of a cell to a "FALSE" value if certain conditions of an IF statement are met.

this is what I have so far

```
Function active_users(cad_desde As Date, cad_fin As Date, last_log As Date, creacion As Date, per_desde As Date, per_fin As Date, download As Date, bloq As Integer)

Dim result As String
result = "False"

If bloq = 0 Or bloq = 128 Then
    If cad_fin < per_desde And last_log < per_desde Then
        Range("P3").Value = "False"
    ElseIf cad_fin >= per_desde And cad_fin <= download And download <= per_fin And last_log < per_desde Then
        Range("P3").Value = "False"
    End If
End If

End Function
```

when I execute the function, I get a "#VALUE!" and if I make a error checking , it tells me that one of the values types used in the formula is incorrect, but it should be noted that this only happens if I add the line "Range (" P3 "). Value =" False "". Otherwise the function is executed, although clearly without giving any results other than a "0" in the cell.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the use of a function that writes its result in a fixed cell?

Comment: Also you should fully qualify ranges to start with. There is no way to tell on what worksheet of what workbook this cell P3 is going to be.

Comment: None. At the moment I'm just trying to make it work. I'm really not sure how I should put together that part of the code in order to get the result dynamically.

Comment: Also, have you considered using a `Boolean` response rather `String`?

Comment: To make a function work, you could have a look at this tutorial: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html

Comment: @urdearboy No, what would it be like?

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks, I'll give it a look!

Comment: The function never returns anything, and no return type is defined. Make it a sub, or instead of updating P5 or whatever, return the value

Comment: I'd honestly scrape the question altogether and then [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55595538/edit), doing a better job explaining what you want to achieve - eg. input and expected result. As of now, it's impossible to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Function` is used when we need to get a value out of it, if no value is meant to be retrieve then probably better use a `Subroutine`.

I change your `Function` to return a Boolean value, which will be `False` if conditions are meet. and I'm updating `Range("P3")` on the `Sub` that calls the `Function`.

So it would look something like this...

```
Option Explicit
Sub Change_Cell_To_False()

Dim result As String
result = active_users("4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/15/2019", "4/1/2019", " 4/20/2019", "4/20/2019", "4/21/2019", 0)

If result = False Then
ActiveSheet.Range("P3") = "False"
End If

End Sub

Private Function active_users(ByVal cad_desde As Date, ByVal cad_fin As Date, ByVal last_log As Date, ByVal creacion As Date, ByVal per_desde As Date, ByVal per_fin As Date, ByVal download As Date, ByValbloq As Integer) As Boolean

If bloq = 0 Or bloq = 128 Then
    If cad_fin < per_desde And last_log < per_desde Then
        active_users = False
    ElseIf cad_fin >= per_desde And cad_fin <= download And download <= per_fin And last_log < per_desde Then
        active_users = False
    Else
        active_users = True
    End If
End If

End Function
```